# Referential Integrity SQL

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have two tables in mysql. Table A has primary key CertID with thousands of certifiactes.
It also has a  key UserID. Table B has primary key UserID. 
Table B has UserID which are NOT in Table A. What I mean is we have UserID in Table A who do not appear in Table B. However all UserID in Table B can be found in Table A.
Is referential integrity possible?
How can I enforce referential integrity here?

Comment: @meisam-mulla I understand about joins. My boss wants me to implement RI.

Answer (score 0):

It just means that tableA's `UserID` is dependent on tableB's `UserID`. But tableB is not dependent on tableA. The schema looks like this,

```
CREATE TABLEB
(
    UserID INT,
    ......,
    CONSTRAINT tb_pk PRIMARY KEY (USERID)
);

CREATE TABLEA
(
    CertID INT,
    UserID INT,
    .....,
     CONSTRAINT tb_pk1 PRIMARY KEY (CertID),
     CONSTRAINT tb_fk FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES tableB(UserID)
);
```

you can insert any records on tableB. But on tableA, if you're trying to insert record, be sure that the value of userID must exist first on tableB's `UserID` or other wise you'll get an error

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): cannot add or update a child row....
```

Comment: I see what you mean. But from my question with the table as it is, can I enforce RI?

Answer (score 0):

You can't enforce   `referential integrity`   here, because TableA has item in UserID column which is not present in UserID column in TableB,

but you can use  `join`  to get value from two table even with out any  referential integrity constraint.

Answer (score 0):

On a high level, referential integrity in MySQL is governed by which storage engine you are using.

Earlier storage engines didn't support referential integrity at all, but newer storage engines like InnoDB ( the default on new installations, I believe ) do support it.

Check your storage engine to see if it even supports referential integrity.  InnoDB would be a good shout.  (Once/if) you are using an engine that supports referential integrity, you'll need to define foreign key constraints to define the relationships.

A useful primer can be found here:-

http://blogs.sakienvirotech.com/index.php/random/2011/09/19/mysql-101-referential-integrity

Comment: Thanks Paul. I do have InnoDB engine. What I just want to find out is: Is it possible to enforce RI with the tables in question without deleting unmatched values in Table B?

Comment: No, the whole point of referential integrity is that you don't have orphaned child records that don't have a parent.  Have you considered archiving the child records off somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Referential integrity means more than just a basic foreign key. It also asks the question, what happens if the row with a certain UserID is deleted or changed in Table B. This is a business question and you can either cascade the changes. Cascaded delete means if you delete the user, you want to delete the links for that user to certificates, cascaded update means that changing the userID in Table B will also change the corresponding value in Table A. Set to NULL means that if you delete the user, you want to keep their link records but set the user ID in Table A to NULL and do nothing means that you will not be allowed to delete or update the row in Table B while there is a reference to it in Table A.

Referential integrity is a bit of a blanket term and doesn't mean the same in every context. It only has integrity related to a specific system or implementation.